# Performing joins in JSONiq (e.g., with the filter syntax)

Tags: json, database, join, flwor, jsoniq

I'm fairly new to JSONiq and I need help with writing a join using a filter.

Let's say I have two collections, $C1 and $C2

I want to find (join/filter) all of the items in $C2 by matching ID between $C1 and $C2 but since $C1 is a collection, i can't do what I usually do, which is

`let $filteredC2 := $C2[$C2.ID eq 5]`, i learned this way of joining/filtering from a tutorial online unfortunately this is as complicated as the example gets,

when I write `let $filteredC2 := $C2[$C2.ID eq $C1.ID]` i get the following error:
`sequence of more than one item cannot be promoted to parameter type xs:anyAtomicType? of function value-equal()`

I understand the issue is obviously I can't do `eq $collection`, but how else can I write this filter so that I find all the items from $C2 that has the same ID as $C1? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are indeed fully supported by JSONiq. There are two approaches:

- With the where clause (like in SQL):

  ```
  for $c1 in $C1
  for $c2 in $C2
  where $c1.ID eq $c2.ID
  (: more clauses :)
  return { (: any combination of data coming from $c1 or $c2 :) }
  ```
- With a predicate:

  ```
  for $c1 in $C1
  for $c2 in $C2[$$.ID eq $c1.ID]
  (: more clauses :)
  return { (: any combination of data coming from $c1 or $c2 :) }
  ```

JSONiq also supports semi-outer joins, for example if there is no match for $c1 in $C2:

```
  for $c1 in $C1
  for $c2 allowing empty in $C2[$$.ID eq $c1.ID]
  (: more clauses :)
  return { (: any combination of data coming from $c1 or $c2 :) }
```

Finally, JSONiq allows you to denormalize data with joins by nesting data coming from C2 into C1:

```
for $c1 in $C1
let $c2 := $C2[$$.ID eq $c1.ID]
(: more clauses :)
return {|
  $c1,
  { "C2" : [ $c2 ] }
|}
```

Each engine optimizes joins in different ways. [RumbleDB](https://www.rumbledb.org) can detect many join patterns (also more complex than those shown above) to avoid a full Cartesian product computation on large quantities of data.

Comment: thanks, i understand that kind of join is possible, but am just wondering if using $$ filter, i can do the same since it seems to be less tedious

Comment: You can alternatively include the filter in the return clause: `for $c1 in $C1 return {........ $C2[$$.ID eq $c1.ID] ...... }`. Engines may or may not find a way to optimize this, however so it will work on small datasets but might be slow on larger datasets. Is it what you were looking for?